# Why does JSON null not cast to SQL null in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, casting, null

So the following PostgreSQL snippet returns `null`, as it should:

```
select ('{"id": null}'::json->'id')
```

Intuitively, one would expect the following statement to return `null` or an empty string:

```
select ('{"id": null}'::json->'id')::TEXT
```

Instead it returns the string "null". Why?

Additionally,

```
select ('{"id": null}'::json->'id')::INTEGER
```

returns `cannot cast type json to integer` and

```
select ('{"id": null}'::json->'id')::TEXT::INTEGER
```

returns `invalid input syntax for integer: "null"`. (The use case here is casting a JSON null to a SQL null in an INTEGER column.)

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283125/why-cant-null-be-converted-to-jsons-null-in-postgresql) with a somewhat-unintelligible answer that seems to boil down to "JSON nulls and SQL nulls are slightly different" and no further explanation. Can someone help me understand what is going on here? This apparent behavior seems crazy!

How does one get around this cleanly? Testing for string "null" screams of code stink, and refactoring to test every single potential node for null/"null" before casting is equally yuck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator for retrieving the json field.

This should work and return `null` (as in, no value) correctly for both:

```
select ('{"id": null}'::json->>'id')::text
select ('{"id": null}'::json->>'id')::integer
```

I've [made a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/10948) that demostrates it

*PS: to get the string `"null"`, you'd need to define your json as: `{"id": "null"}`*

Comment: This works exactly the way I was expecting it to. Thank you! The other comment mentioned this too but yours was posted first so I'll give this answer the credit.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to use the json_typeof operator to figure out what you have in the JSON type that is returned by ->

```sql
select json_typeof('{"id": 4}'::json->'id'),
       json_typeof('{"id": "null"}'::json->'id'),
       json_typeof('{"id": null}'::json->'id');
```

Using ->> instead guarantees you a text string value, but then you cannot distinguish between null and "null"

Comment: Thanks for the json_typeof note, unfortunately production is running 9.3 and this feature isn't available on that release

Comment: The last part of this answer is incorrect. `->>` will yield a proper SQL NULL value for a jsonb null value. Try e.g.: `\pset null SQLNULL` followed by `SELECT ('{"foo":null}'::jsonb->>'foo') IS NULL, ('{"foo":null}'::jsonb->>'foo'), ('{"foo":"null"}'::jsonb->>'foo') IS NULL, ('{"foo":"null"}'::jsonb->>'foo');`