# Best practice to identify a jsonb null in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm aware that variants of this question have been asked before:

- [Why can't NULL be converted to JSON's null in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283125/why-cant-null-be-converted-to-jsons-null-in-postgresql)
- [Why does JSON null not cast to SQL null in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172873/why-does-json-null-not-cast-to-sql-null-in-postgres)
- perhaps others...

What I wasn't able to glean from the above links is whether there is a best practice.

Consider the following code:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  _main_jsonb jsonb = '{"i_am_null": null, "a_string": "null"}';
  _sub_jsonb jsonb;
BEGIN
  SELECT (_main_jsonb->'i_am_null') INTO _sub_jsonb;
  IF _sub_jsonb IS NULL THEN
    RAISE INFO 'This point *not* reached. Bad?';
  END IF;

  -- THIS IS THE PART I AM REALLY INTERESTED IN
  SELECT (_main_jsonb->>'i_am_null')::jsonb INTO _sub_jsonb;
  IF _sub_jsonb IS NULL THEN
    RAISE INFO 'This point *is* reached. Good.';
  END IF;
  -- THIS IS THE PART I AM REALLY INTERESTED IN

  SELECT (_main_jsonb->>'a_string')::jsonb INTO _sub_jsonb;
  IF _sub_jsonb IS NULL THEN
    RAISE INFO 'Bonus points. This point *not* reached. Good.';
  END IF;
END;
$$
```

Is there a better way to figure out if i_am_null is null?

Edit: FYI to those interested in this question, [you might be interested in this follow-up question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587601/are-there-different-flavors-of-null-in-a-postgresql-plpgsql-variable-of-type-jso)

Comment: What do you mean by "*true null*"?

Comment: One of those two variations of the question that I linked in did discuss a string value of "null", so I distinguished null from "null". Frankly, none of my code is going to pass "null" anyway. I just edited my final question, though, if that helps

Comment: `= NULL` will never match. I think you are looking for `= 'null'::jsonb`. This will not match sql `NULL` however, as returned by `_main_jsonb->'i_do_not_exist'`, not sure what is desired there.

Comment: @Bergi thx the `= NULL` was a hail Mary, to be sure. I threw it in there because one of the answers to the variations on this question mentioned that "JSON nulls and SQL nulls are slightly different" -- so I went wild and considered the impossible... but I've now removed that distraction from my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your linked answers contain solutions, but it might be good to have an omnibus answer.

Postgres is strongly typed. Its functions and operators return specific types.

`->` returns jsonb. [Compare it not to SQL null but jsonb null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220879/14660).

```
test=# select '{"i_am_null": null, "a_string": "null"}'::jsonb->'i_am_null' = 'null'::jsonb;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

test=# select '{"i_am_null": null, "a_string": "null"}'::jsonb->'a_string' = 'null'::jsonb;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

---

`->>` returns text and [will convert jsonb null into SQL null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39173083/14660).

```
test=# select '{"i_am_null": null, "a_string": "null"}'::jsonb->>'i_am_null' is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

test=# select '{"i_am_null": null, "a_string": "null"}'::jsonb->>'a_string' is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

---

Note that while jsonb null is just another value, SQL null is very special. Null is not a value, it is the lack of a value. [Null equals nothing, not even null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). It might seem like casting null to jsonb should produce jsonb null, but the SQL standard requires that ***null only casts to null*** otherwise that would mean null is equivalent to something.

This is why jsonb null can be converted to null, but null is not cast to jsonb null. ***`null::jsonb` is null***. This is inconvenient, but required by the SQL standard. It is one of the reasons casting back and forth between jsonb and text is not recommended.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I was in the middle of puzzling over why `select 'null'::jsonb::text is null;` is false. I guess `->>` has its own logic.

Comment: As I digest this, I find myself still confused, though. (_main_jsonb->'i_am_null') is jsonb. And so is (_main_jsonb->>'i_am_null')::jsonb. Right? But only one of them can successfully be compared to SQL NULL. I'd love this answer to cover that, if I am making sense.

Comment: @Wellspring They are not equivalent. `(_main_jsonb->'i_am_null')` is jsonb. `(_main_jsonb->>'i_am_null')::jsonb` is jsonb converted to text and cast back to jsonb.

Comment: @Wellspring A more complete answer: `_main_jsonb->>'i_am_null'` converts the jsonb null to SQL null. SQL null cast to jsonb is SQL null. While `_main_jsonb->'i_am_null'` simply returns jsonb null.

Comment: that's precisely what confuses me. Both are "eventually" jsonb. But only one of the eventual values is comparable to `SQL NULL`. What is the representation of these two jsonb values? Clearly in "binary" or something, the two things stored in `_sub_jsonb` are not the same, and yet both are proper jsonb...

Comment: @Wellspring It's not the internal representation, it's the *return type*. Postgres is strongly typed. `->` returns jsonb so you get jsonb null. `->>` returns text so you get text, which can be null. null is equal to nothing, ***null cannot be cast to any value*** which includes jsonb null, so `null::jsonb` is null.

Comment: @Wellspring The problem with `->>` is that it converts different json types to text in different ways. Maybe [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b13a9984ad6404cdb496ae654987bd6) is helpful. Commenting in the first line demonstrates why casting string fields back to jsonb is a bad idea.

Comment: Thx Bergi and @Schwern -- forgive me if I have the protocols wrong on next moves, but your help is much appreciated and my next question doesn't fit in a comment. I will edit the question itself, and adjust if given guidance after that.

Comment: @Wellspring Please leave the question as is and ask a new question. Changing an answered question makes all the answers and comments nonsensical. Feel free to link to the question here and we'll have a look.

Comment: [Updated demo fiddle (better-formatted, more examples)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=798e3d556ede7798a394c3bc876b4bcc)

Answer (score 2):

There is `jsonb_typeof()` function:

> `json_typeof ( json ) → text`
>
> `jsonb_typeof ( jsonb ) → text`
>
> Returns the type of the top-level JSON value as a text string. Possible types are `object, array, string, number, boolean, and null`. (The `null` result should not be confused with a SQL `NULL`; see the examples.)
>
> `json_typeof('-123.4') → number`
>
> `json_typeof('null'::json) → null`
>
> `json_typeof(NULL::json) IS NULL → t`

[Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
with t(x) as (values('{"i_am_null": null, "a_string": "null"}'::jsonb))
select
    *,
    jsonb_typeof(x->'i_am_null') as "i_am_null",
    jsonb_typeof(x->'a_string') as "a_string",
    jsonb_typeof(x->'foo') as "foo"
from t;

┌─────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────┐
│                    x                    │ i_am_null │ a_string │ foo  │
├─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────┤
│ {"a_string": "null", "i_am_null": null} │ null      │ string   │ ░░░░ │
└─────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

So `if jsonb_typeof(some_jsonb_value) = 'null' then ...` is what you want as I understood.

Note that the existing key `i_am_null` returns the text `'null'` and missed key `foo` returns SQL `NULL`.

Comment: So would you agree then that `IF _sub_jsonb = 'null'::jsonb` and `IF jsonb_typeof(some_jsonb_value) = 'null'` are functional equivalents? And if so, is this a tomAyto / tomAHto thing or is there a best practice recommendation? If not, I suppose the method that is fastest would be the one to go with.

Comment: add `(jsonb_typeof(x->'foo') as "foo") is null`  would be great.