# Are there different flavors of null in a PostgreSQL plpgsql variable of type jsonb?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

[Following up on a question I asked here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586539/best-practice-to-identify-a-jsonb-null-in-plpgsql)

[@Bergi provided a helpful fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b13a9984ad6404cdb496ae654987bd6) which produces the following table...

```
+------------------+--------+------+--------+
|       val        |   ->   | ->>  | ->> :: |
+------------------+--------+------+--------+
| {"prop": "null"} | "null" | null | null   |
| {"prop": null}   | null * |      | **     |
| {"prop": 42}     | 42     | 42   | 42     |
| {"prop": []}     | []     | []   | []     |
| {"prop": {}}     | {}     | {}   | {}     |
| {}               |        |      |        |
+------------------+--------+------+--------+
```

The fiddle link is more clear, but some returns are grey nulls and some are black. And there is clearly meaning in the difference. Anyway, note in particular the *   and ** cells.

Note now two snippets from my OP code...

```
SELECT (_main_jsonb->'i_am_null') INTO _sub_jsonb; -- *
SELECT (_main_jsonb->>'i_am_null')::jsonb INTO _sub_jsonb; -- **
```

So first question is -- what precisely is being *stored* in _sub_jsonb in the * case? I understand that _sub_jsonb is being initialized by a different sequences of casts, but I do not understand what is actually being stored in _sub_jsonb in the first case. Clearly something different... a null that's not a null, somehow.

My second question is a re-ask of best practices, because I think I gleaned from a passing comment from Bergi (" Commenting in the first line demonstrates why casting string fields back to jsonb is a bad idea. ") that I should probably stick with this (below) approach to discovering nulls, as best practice:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  _main_jsonb jsonb = '{"i_am_null": null}';
  _sub_jsonb jsonb;
BEGIN
  SELECT (_main_jsonb->'i_am_null') INTO _sub_jsonb;
  IF _sub_jsonb = 'null'::jsonb THEN
    RAISE INFO 'Best practice to identify a jsonb null. I think.';
  END IF;
END;
$$
```

Did I read your guidance rightly, Bergi?

Thx again, Bergi and Schwern!

Comment: Grey nulls are the SQL `NULL` value that can be the result of any expression, black nulls are jsonb values (or strings respectively)

Comment: So a SQL null proper can actually be stored in jsonb -- and it's different from a "jsonb null". Wow. No wonder I've been confused. Different classes of null -- in the same type. Yikes.

Comment: "*what precisely is being stored*" - an SQL `NULL` value means nothing is stored there. `'null'::jsonb` is just a value of type jsonb, like an object or array or number

Comment: And I guess I should refrain from treating jsonb as SQL... i.e. avoid using "IS NULL". This has been a laborious learning process but thank you so much for all the input!